# Where to get the "SignalSystem" mathematica package?

Tags: signal-processing, compatibility

I am reading this book: Filter Design for Signal Processing Using MATLAB and Mathematica.It can find on the following link:

https://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=3841

It's mathmatica examples on the books need the mathematica package "SSP”，but the two link the author provide to download the book example codes are no longer accessible.And I find it seems to be the same with the following package "SingalSystem":

https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/applications/signals/RepresentingSignalsandSystems.html

But it is plity this is an obsolete product.where I can get the "SignalSystem" package? Anyone help? Thanks！

Comment: Have you tried http://web.archive.org/ ?

Comment: Also note that most signal processing activities, especially filter design, are now in the standard code for Mathematica. Were there special functions that you needed? I am sure that if you ask here we can help.

Comment: Seems that you can read Chinese, then I suggest reading this: https://note.youdao.com/ynoteshare1/index.html?id=0c2719208239696d61182199327bd38c&type=note

Comment: Yes, I have try on this website. I am learning sigal processing, but it seems that there are too few books for signal processing using mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

This third party application is no longer sold by Wolfram.

There is an old description of it [here](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/faq/mma_notes/Mathematica_for_signal_processing.htm)

I have the application still that I bought in 2005:

[image]

But I made no attempt to install in on recent Mathematica versions, as I am sure it will not work or install on Mathematica any more.

btw, it is not a Mathematica package. It was an add-on application written by 3rd party, which can be added and used from inside Mathematica then.

Wolfram used to sell many more 3rd party applications. But as they added those functionalities into Mathematica, those were no longer sold by Wolfram. For historical purposes, I still have all these applications, that can no longer be used on recent Mathematica (At least I have not tried to install them now, I am afraid it might break something if I try)

`structural_mechanics_1_0_2`

[image]

`control_systems_v_2_0_2`

[image]

`control_systems_v_2_1`

[image]

`Digital image processing 1.1.1`

[image]

`Mathematica advanced numerical methods`

[image]
`
[image]

And may be few more around my old computer.

Most of the functionalities in these, are now build in Mathematica,

Comment: Hi ,Nasser, thanks for your reply. I just want to learn the course of signal processing in mathematica through this book. Could you send these me these application files？And which version of mathematica it can work well?

Comment: And this is my e-mail: dirlianhua@gmail.com